# Does BCP QUERYOUT block the source table?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

How does this work? I know `BCP OUT` works in its own transaction (not the C# SqlBulkCopy, but the bcp.exe utility), but it has to read in read committed isolation level.

I have done several tests and it all seems to work perfectly fine by not blocking any reads or writes happening at the source table while the tool runs.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Why do you expect it would? By default the query engine will only lock rows for as long as necessary, not the entire table. If you try something drastic like `DELETE FROM table`, the `DELETE` should definitely block while the copying is going on. (Also, if your database uses `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`, then no `READ COMMITTED` query will ever block on data modifications.)

Answer (score 0):

BCP with the queryout option does not block anything. Whether or not any blocking occurs is dependent on what you enter as the "query" to be executed. Whether or not blocking occurs is not a question for BCP, it does not care about your query. It just send it so SQL Server... and SQL Server decides if blocking is needed. This is no different than if you executed the query from a query tool.